# how to add some html line on javascript alert box

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an alert box with some details but my code is not working, please help me.

```
<script>
alert('<ul>
 <li>Language must be in english .</li>
 <li>Topic's must be on Digitalcoin.</li>
 <li>Write a good title.</li>
 <li>Don't give <b>Read More</b> button with other sites link.</li>
</ul>',{
  ok : 'Ok'
})
</script>
```

Comment: So what is `alert()` since the default `window.alert()` does not support that. And JavaScript does not support line breaks in strings like that.

Comment: so how can i show <ul>
 <li>Language must be in english .</li>
 <li>Topic's must be on Digitalcoin.</li>
 <li>Write a good title.</li>
 <li>Don't give <b>Read More</b> button with other sites link.</li>
</ul> on alert box .

Comment: You can not do that with window.alert() it does not support HTML, just plain text. If you need to display html, you need to look at a modal dialog library.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you can't put html in the native JavaScript's alert. You can use jquery's dialog or bootstart's alert, here examples:

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom alert box to allow `html` markup. Or you can use a library like @epascarello has mentioned. Here is a [great article on how to create your own modal box with html5 and css3](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/). I have gone ahead and created a starting point.

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0h3mLcpn/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You may use an alternative workaround to such a problem by creating div elements with some content then toggle hide/show using JavaScript. See the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

#adddiv {
display: none; 
text-align: center;
width: 80%; /*border-radius: 25px;*/ 
border: 2px solid Black; 
padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; 
margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
//background: #fff//#A4D3EE; 
overflow: visible; 
box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888; 
position: relative; } 
#xadd { position: absolute; 
background: yellow; 
color: black; top: -10px; 
right: -10px; }
#add { position: absolute; 
background: #3caea3;//#3c99dc; 
color: white; }

#deldiv {
display: none;
text-align: center;
width: 80%; /*border-radius: 25px;*/ 
border: 2px solid Black; 
padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; 
margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
//background: #fff//#A4D3EE; 
overflow: visible; 
box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888; 
position: relative; }
#xdel { position: absolute; 
background: blue; 
color: white; top: -10px; 
right: -10px; }
#del { position: absolute; 
background: red;//#3c99dc; 
color: white; }
</style>
<script>
function myFunctionaddopen() {
var x = document.getElementById("adddiv");
if (x.style.display !== "none") {
  x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
    </script>
<script>
function myFunctionaddclose() {
var x = document.getElementById("adddiv");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
  //x.style.display = "block";
} else {
x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

<script>
function myFunctiondelopen() {
var x = document.getElementById("deldiv");
if (x.style.display !== "none") {
  x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
    </script>
<script>
function myFunctiondelclose() {
var x = document.getElementById("deldiv");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
  //x.style.display = "block";
} else {
x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the action buttons below to open the modals:</p>

<button id="add" onclick="myFunctionaddopen()">button_1</button>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<button id="del" onclick="myFunctiondelopen()">button_2</button>

<div id="adddiv">
This is the first modal Exit by clicking on the "x" button at the top right coner.
<button id="xadd" onclick="myFunctionaddclose()">x</button>
</div>

<div id="deldiv">
This is the second modal Exit by clicking on the "x" button at the top right coner.
<button id="xdel" onclick="myFunctiondelclose()">x</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```